# Prevent text selection/highlighting in a content editable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Is there way to create a content-editable div where users can't select/highlight content but can still input things? I want to create an interface where users are forced to delete and enter things key-by-key, without being able to make mass edits via highlighting.

I've looked into the various forms of the "user-select" property in CSS, which works for static content, but doesn't seem to work for content-editable elements/inputs.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You need to use DOM for that kind of usage. I don't think CSS or HTML would simply do that.

Comment: why would you want to take away such a common and accessible feature? I'd curse, double-curse and then triple-curse a person who'd do such a thing to me, so just curious :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I'll look into lower level DOM control and a non-contenteditable model. I want viewers to be able to follow along when someone writes -mass highlight-deletes and cursor re-positions would be confusing to follow. Also, I want to promote stream-of-conscious writing so I'm trying to limit the amount of editing power writers have. I'll post back here when I figure it out.

Comment: Don't forget these aren't idiot proof, anybody who wants to steal your text, can.  Any webdev can disable your CSS/HTML/JS.  They can also just VIEW SOURGE and copy'n'paste the text.

Comment: @TravisO Looks like OP is not trying to prevent copying the content of the page, rather the case is to prevent too fast/large changes to a particular element.

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept a `textarea` instead of a contenteditable `div`, you can do something like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var div = document.getElementById('div');
    if (div.attachEvent) {
        div.attachEvent('onselectstart', function (e) {
            e.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        });
        div.attachEvent('onpaste', function (e) {
            e.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        });
    } else {
        div.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        div.addEventListener('select', function (e) {
            var start = this.selectionStart,
                end = this.selectionEnd;
            if (this.selectionDirection === 'forward') {
                this.setSelectionRange(end, end);
            } else {
                this.setSelectionRange(start, start);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

HTML:

```
<form>
    <textarea id="div"></textarea>
</form>
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5xrqv/3/).

Some observations on the code:

- In many browsers [`onselect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/select) is fired only for `input` or `textarea` elements within a `form`. That is a reason for the different HTML from yours.
- IE9 - 10 don't support `selectionDirection`, that's why IE's legacy event handling model is used also for these browsers.
- If not IE, you still can replace a bunch of text by selecting it with mouse and hitting a key *without* releasing the mouse button. I suppose this could be prevented by detecting if the mouse button is down, and in that case preventing keyboard actions. This would be your homework ; ).
- The code for IE works with contenteditable `div`s too.

---

**EDIT**

Looks like I've done [your "homework"](http://jsfiddle.net/5xrqv/3/) too.

Comment: @user2529253 Any comments?

Comment: If i select the text and don't unclick, but write something, the selectable text is still working and the text is changed.

Comment: @IagoMelanias You can't select any text when using the ["homework code"](http://jsfiddle.net/5xrqv/3/).

Comment: Yep, now is working perfectly. I can't select using mouse, ctrl+a and double click on the text. Great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know you want to disable mass deleting, but if others are wanting to not show a highlight color (which would be `user-select: none` for other elements), you can put the following in your css:

```
::selection { background: transparent }
```

This will make the selection look like `user-select: none` but it will still allow mass deleting. But it could make users think there is no selection, so they possibly won't mass delete.

Hope this works for you, but mainly towards others.